# How to get field name in twig template

Tags: views, 8

I have a view. And I want to have some conditions for particular field name in a twig template. the template is `views-view-fields.html` . I have tried with devel modules also. But now getting. Please help.

code:

```
{% for field in fields -%}
   //if field.name == 'something' then do this
{%- endfor %}
```

Comment: There is no way to know what the field names should be only you would know that. You should install Twig XDebug + XDebug so you can set a breakpoint here and see the variables available.

Comment: Thank you. going the other way is it possible to override template for that field only? I tried even that but no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure. My 99% case for Views is to always render the entity in a designated view mode - then you render things as normal (view mode twig override, or fields) which are all respected. I really really avoid field based Views.

Comment: The problem is that I want to add a <video> tag in the rewrite result of a field in a view. But it is not working. what should be the reason.

Comment: This should really be handled with field rendering, which would be handled when rendering the content itself and not individual fields.